# JAVA Email not working properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2

I am using this code to send mail from inside spring application

```
public static void main( final String[] args ) throws MessagingException
{
    System.out.println("<port> <username> <password> <to>");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth",            "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",  "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host",             "smtp.mydomain.in");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port",             args[0].trim());

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
               return new PasswordAuthentication(args[1].trim(),args[2].trim());
            }
      });

    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(args[1].trim()));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(args[3]));
    message.setSubject("test mail");
    message.setContent("test mail body","text/html");
    Transport.send(message);
}
```

**Scanerio where it works**

- If i run it in my local system
- If i use it withing my spring application on my local machine
- If i run it alone in AWS

**Where it doesn't work**

- If i use it withing my spring application on AWS it throws

  ```
  throws javax.mail.MessagingException'.
  javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:   authentication failure

      at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:826)
      at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:761)
      at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:685)
      at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
      at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
      at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
      at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
      at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
  ```

In my actual app i m taking params as:

```
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth",             env.getProperty("mail.smtp.auth").trim());
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",  env.getProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable").trim());
    props.put("mail.smtp.host",             env.getProperty("mail.smtp.host").trim());
    props.put("mail.smtp.port",             env.getProperty("mail.smtp.port").trim());

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
               return new PasswordAuthentication(env.getProperty("username").trim(), env.getProperty("password").trim());
            }
      });
```

Comment: How are you passing arguments (username and password) to Spring application? Are you sure they are correct?

Comment: yes they are correct. i updated my question how i am actually taking params

Comment: Add `setDebug(true)` to your `Session` object and watch the logs for hints.

Comment: I fixed it the problem was in my local machine `env.getProperty("username")` was taking whatevr username i was passing in my prop file but in AWS it was taking `root` as `env.getProperty("username")` so i changed the variable `username`